# WSL2 on Windows 11 (Ubuntu 20.04): cannot run Qt apps, "could not connect to display: :0", xcb module found but not loaded

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qt

**Qt apps work from Terminal-hosted WSL, but not from window WSL**.

I am trying to run a Qt app, such as `xeyes`, on WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04, on Windows 11. When I launch it (xeyes, or Wireshark, or Qt-made software from my company), I have an error: `Error: Can't open display: :0`.

Depending on the software, the error can be detailed as:

```
user@PC:~$ wireshark
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display: :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found
```

---

For the sake of legibility, I will start code lines like that:

- `C:\Users\me> foo` is the Windows terminal (CMD)
- `bash-5.0$ fight` is WSL called from the terminal (in the same window)
- `user@PC:~$` is WSL started from Windows 11, from the desktop, in a separate window. It is supposed to be the exact same thing, but apparently not...

---

The weird thing is that **I can run these if I start WSL2 from CMD**. But not in my main WSL installation, the one that I start from a shortcut on my Windows desktop.

There are a lot of questions on the subject: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323993/clion-with-wsl-try-to-run-qt-application-xcb-can-not-be-loaded), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394866/access-wsl2-ubuntus-application-on-hosted-machines-network), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1580610/how-to-run-gui-apps-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux). None of the solutions work for my system. My takeaway is that on start-up, WSL changes a network configuration.

### How to reproduce

If I open Terminal (Windows command invite) and start WSL from there, it works:

```
C:\Users\me> wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile
bash-5.0$ xeyes               # --> xeyes work
```

But if I open WSL *directly* from Windows, it does not work.

```
user@PC:~$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

And the weird thing is, **once I opened WSL2**, I can't start the app from CMD-hosted WSL again.

```
C:\Users\me> wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile
bash-5.0$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0
```

My conclusion is that **something in WSL2 changed network settings at launch**.

### Possible leads

I tried changing the `DISPLAY` variable.

- `user@PC:~$ export DISPLAY=0.0.0.0` --> same error
- `user@PC:~$ export DISPLAY=0.0.0.0:0` --> runs for several minutes, then same error
- `user@PC:~$ export DISPLAY=10.0.0.3` (local IP) --> same error
- `user@PC:~$ export DISPLAY=10.0.0.3:0` --> runs for several minutes, then same error
- `user@PC:~$ export DISPLAY=[route]` putting the default route --> same error

In all cases, the problem must not be `DISPLAY`, because it has the same default value in CMD and WSL2.

WSL from Windows desktop:

`user@PC:~$ echo $DISPLAY` --> `:0`

WSL from Terminal:

```
C:\Users\me> wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile
bash-5.0$ echo $DISPLAY
bash-5.0$ :0
```

I thought maybe WSL from desktop changes the network settings. But both `ifconfig` and `ip route show` return exactly the same parameters. I also have nothing in my .bashrc that could modify them, at least I think so.

Comment: I think you need to consolidate the three existing questions - Ultimately, they are all towards the same goal, right?

Comment: And just as a heads-up, I think I'm seeing something similar myself now.  Can you add a `wsl --status` to one of your questions?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't think I've asked you yet, but a `wsl -l -v` might be useful (or might not)

Comment: Hey, you're right, I should have consolidated the questions. Thanks for your answers, I'm going through them :)

Here is `wsl --status`:

`Default distribution: Ubuntu`

`Default version: 2`

`Last update: 13/07/2022`

`Auto updates are enabled`

`Core version: 5.10.102.1`

Comment: And here is `wsl -l -v`:

`C:\Users\TRUST-ME>wsl -l -v`
`  NAME       STATE           VERSION`
`* Ubuntu     Running         2`
`  CentOS7    Stopped         2`

I installed CentOS7 for our project, but never used it. I don't think it's the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Windows 10, WSL2 on Ubuntu.

Try the following
`export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="xcb"`
`sudo apt install libxcb-xinerama0 libqt5x11extras5`